# Form not working in specific domain

Tags: php, forms, browser

I add a simple form in [this website](http://www.pateoalfacinha.com/index2.html#!/) and for this specific domain it doesn't work. I've tried in a different domain and it works great.
Can anyone help me figure it out what the problem is? Anyone have a second type of form that works with this specifications?

```js
<?php

$name = $_POST ['name'];
$mobile = $_POST ['mobile'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$subject = $_POST ['subject'];
// $message = $_POST ['message'];
$message = $_POST['message'] . "\n Contacto: " . $_POST['mobile'];
$to = "rodolfovieiradias@gmail.com";
// $subject = "" . $mobile;

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $email);
echo "<div style ='font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;line-height: 15px;color:white;background-color: green;padding: 5px;text-align: -webkit-center;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;'>Your message has been sent!</div>";
?>
```

```html
<form action="backend/form_processEN.php" method="post" name="contact_form" id="contact_form" target="myIframe" autocomplete="on">

           <fieldset>
            <div>
             <label for="name" accesskey="U">Name</label>
             <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div>
             <label for="mobile" accesskey="P">Phone</label>
             <input name="mobile" type="tel" id="phone" size="30" placeholder="Enter your phone number" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div>
             <label for="email" accesskey="E">Email</label>
             <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div>
             <label for="subject" accesskey="W">Subject</label>
             <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" placeholder="What&acute;s the subject?" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div>
             <label for="comments" accesskey="C">Message</label>
             <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" placeholder="Leave your message..." spellcheck="true" required="required"></textarea>
            </div>
           </fieldset>

           <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >
           <iframe name="myIframe" frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-style: none; margin-left: 65px; width: 240px; height: 40px;"></iframe>
           
          </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: With a different domain name it works ?

Comment: In here: http://www.refeel.pt/teste/001/002/index2.html#!/page_Contact

Comment: it just worked with me, so the one you posted before doesnt ?

Comment: The error coming back is `The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.` , you are using IIS as a web server, you will need to check why it is not allowing a `POST` to go through, check this : https://forums.iis.net/t/1154637.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to make sure that the "From" email is actually on the server you are sending from - i.e. not an @gmail.com address.

This explains it quite well for mail and shows how to add a "reply to" for `mail();`.
http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/email.php

Remember to sanitise any textfield input information to avoid inject attacks.

You might also try setting the `sendmail_from` ini setting in php
`ini_set("sendmail_from","you@yourserver.com");` 
Drop that in at the top of your php.

PHP Mailer is also a solid alternative method for emailing, which I prefer personally. Using PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer gives you the ability to add a "reply-to" to your email, which avoids the return email going back to your server and will address it to your visitor.

Comment: Thank you Steve for your quick answer.
I've change the email sender to an existed in the server.
Did I made it right? Because it still don't work... :(

'<?php

ini_set("sendmail_from","comercial@pateoalfacinha.com");

?>'

Comment: I think @Rabee Abdelwahab 's answer might be onto something in your case - he found the error message which points to that issue - though the code you have should work for the ini settings, minus the brackets and single inverted commas. of course.. Have a look at the last link on the page he sent you a link for.

Comment: May be a silly thought, but have you tried the form with a full http... URL for the php processing form? The target being a iframe might also be worth experimenting with removing.